# Bootstrap 3.0 navigation on page resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Bootstrap and just attempting to get the responsive navigation to work. When I resize the window, I do see the collapsed navbar icon but it doesn't display the `add` link.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">      
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>



                <a href="{{ action('BooksController@index') }}" class="navbar-brand">My Books</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ action('BooksController@create') }}" class="navbar-brand">Add</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include bootstrap.js?

Comment: @DieterGoetelen: Yes I have. Do I need to include JQuery as well?

Comment: Jep and jQuery has to be included before bootstrap.js. In the future first check your chrome dev tools for console errors ;-). It'll help you alot and it is time saving.

Comment: Yeah done. I've checked the dev tools and there's no errors. It like nothing is firing when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

In fact should be:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#.navbar-collapse">
```

`data-target` should be the class name of the `nav div`.